# Can I add listeners to Multiple Databases in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Regarding the recent announcement of the multi-database support within a Firebase project, can we add listeners to multiple databases? Or should we connect to maximum one database at a time?

For example, let's say that I have created two databases, `DB-1` and `DB-2`. I want to add a listener for changes in `node-A` in `DB-1` and another listener in `node-B` in `DB-2`. Is this possible? I've read the documentation but it's a bit contradicting:

> Each app instance only connects to one database at any given moment.

...

> If each client needs to connect to multiple databases during a session, you can reduce the number of simultaneous connections to each database instance by connecting to each database instance for only as long as is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly connect to multiple databases at the same time, according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding#connect_your_app_to_multiple_database_instances).  There may be cases when you want to reduce the active number of active connections your app is making, especially if you have a lot of shards, each with a lot of activity, so the advice stands for those cases, if this applies to you.

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks for the answer, can you elaborate what the documentation means by saying that _"Each app instance only connects to one database at any given moment."_?

Comment: It's talking about FirebaseApp object instances, not you app that you wrote.